# Kivy AsyncImage not cache photo

Tags: kivy

My Kivy app loads photo from URLs and works fine.
But I found it not cache the photo just loaded.
(large photo and every time takes few seconds).
I have tried `nocache : False` but no help.
I have another http request and use `requests-cache`,
it only cache on that http request but not the `AsyncImage`.
How to use Kivy AsyncImage cache and control it for example expire etc.
My app's code looks like below.
Thanks in advance.

```py
AsyncImage:
    id: bg_img_1
    source: app.photo_url_1
    nocache: False

class MainApp(App):
    def press_refresh(self):
        self.bg_img_1.reload()   # reload photo but without cache.
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are attempting to accomplish, but the `reload()` method is intended to reload the image from the source, not the cache.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the `nocache : False` option the photo should load from internal cache,( https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.image.html#kivy.uix.image.Image.nocache )
The `bg_img_1` photo should be reloaded from the cache. 
Anything I am missing?

Comment: The `nocache` setting does not affect the `reload()` operation except that the image is not added to the cache if `nocache` is `True`. By the way, why would you ever want to reload from the cache? That would essentially be a no-op.

Comment: The photo is a little bit large and not change very often(30 min). If the user press refresh button may see the loading of photo. 
I use requests_cache to cache every JSON response, it works fine.